# Spartacus 3.3 - Extend Spartacus NgRx store to add subscription orders feature

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store, spartacus-storefront

For our Spartacus project we need add the subscriptions orders feature.
To do this I think we will have to extend the mapped data model (OrderEntry) present in the default NgRx OOTB store, but I don't think it will be enough.

Which is the proper way to extend the NgRx store data model and related stuff (facade, connector, adapter, ecc.)? Anyone who had deal with similar task here? I searched the documentation thoroughly but found nothing about it.

Any inputs or support would be very appreciated. :-)